# I want to add 12 pictures in one page without entering the writing between pictures

Tags: pdf

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{0000.png}
\caption*{(a)}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{11.png}
\caption*{(b)}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{22.png}
\caption*{(c)}
\endminipage
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{33.png}
\caption*{(d)}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{44.png}
\caption*{(e)}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{55.png}
\caption*{(f)}
\endminipage
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{66.png}
\caption*{(g)}
\endminipage\hfill
 \minipage{0.32\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{77.png}
\caption*{(h)}
 \endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{88.png}
\caption*{(i)}
\endminipage
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{99.png}
\caption*{(j)}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{100.png}
\caption*{(k)}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{110.png}
\caption*{(l)}
\endminipage
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Zoom de image 2.3.a de Munich (a)Image Optique (b)Image Span (c)Robert (d)Prewitt (e)Sobel (f)moyenneur(3$ \times $3) (g)moyenneur( (h)Canny (i)Emboss  (j)DOG (k)Laplacien (l)Résultat.}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\begin{figure}[p]
    \minipage{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{0000.png}
    \caption*{(a)}
    \endminipage\hfill
    \minipage{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{11.png}
    \caption*{(b)}
    \endminipage\hfill
    \minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{22.png}
    \caption*{(c)}
    \endminipage

    \minipage{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{33.png}
    \caption*{(d)}
    \endminipage\hfill
    \minipage{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{44.png}
    \caption*{(e)}
    \endminipage\hfill
    \minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{55.png}
    \caption*{(f)}
    \endminipage

    \minipage{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{66.png}
    \caption*{(g)}
    \endminipage\hfill
    \minipage{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{77.png}
    \caption*{(h)}
    \endminipage\hfill
    \minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{88.png}
    \caption*{(i)}
    \endminipage

    \minipage{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{99.png}
    \caption*{(j)}
    \endminipage\hfill
    \minipage{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{100.png}
    \caption*{(k)}
    \endminipage\hfill
    \minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{110.png}
    \caption*{(l)}
    \endminipage
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \caption{Zoom de image 2.3.a de Munich (a)Image Optique (b)Image Span (c)Robert (d)Prewitt (e)Sobel 
    (f)moyenneur(3$ \times $3) (g)moyenneur( (h)Canny (i)Emboss  (j)DOG (k)Laplacien (l)Résultat.}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

However, using package `subcaption` and macro `\subfigure` would make more sense.

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{0000.png}}  
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{11.png}}    
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{22.png}}    

\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{33.png}}    
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{44.png}}    
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{55.png}}    

\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{66.png}}    
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{77.png}}    
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{88.png}}    

\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{99.png}}    
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{100.png}}   
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{110.png}}   

\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Zoom de image 2.3.a de Munich (a)Image Optique (b)Image Span (c)Robert (d)Prewitt (e)Sobel 
        (f)moyenneur(3$ \times $3) (g)moyenneur( (h)Canny (i)Emboss  (j)DOG (k)Laplacien (l)Résultat.}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

with `subfloat` environments and `Gin` key:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
   \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.32\linewidth}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{0000.png}}
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{11.png}}
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{22.png}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{33.png}}
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{44.png}}
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{55.png}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{66.png}}
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{77.png}}
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{88.png}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{99.png}}
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{100.png}}
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{110.png}}
%
\caption{Zoom de image 2.3.a de Munich (a)Image Optique (b)Image Span (c)Robert (d)Prewitt (e)Sobel
    (f)moyenneur(3$ \times $3) (g)moyenneur( (h)Canny (i)Emboss  (j)DOG (k)Laplacien (l)Résultat.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

caption set up i left to you.